# Can ESP32 radiation cause health hazards?

Tags: esp8266, radiation, esp32, risk-analysis

I am using ESP32 chips for a smart health monitoring device.

I will use WiFi 802.11n or Bluetooth BLE/EDR depending on the amount of data to be transferred, so the unit will be mounted on hand, maybe another place of the body.

It can be:

- upper back middle
- lower back middle
- front upper- chest
- wrist
- arm below the shoulder

I could not find any resources for health risks of ESP32 radiation.

Is there any possibility of getting cancer or any other health issues due to Bluetooth or WiFi radiation of the ESP32?

Comment: Really short answer: No. Also, a really short consideration about how many people you know that got sick from the Bluetooth and Wifi of their smartphones would have answered this.

Comment: Does having a cellphone in any of those places cause health hazards? Some people think yes, but most people think no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal RF communications protocols all use non-ionizing radiation, which does not have any serious health concerns. In the worst case, it can heat your body up slightly (like a microwave oven, but at an incredibly low power level compared to the oven. If these were dangerous, we'd all be getting horribly maimed by our phones and laptops.

With that said, because water absorbs 2.4GHz (and thus causes the aforementioned heating), you aren't going to get good signal **out** if you plan on implanting such a device.

Chart from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation:

[image: frequency chart]

Comment: implanted means under the skin?

Comment: @oppo Yes. Implanting an ESP32 is probably a bad idea anyways though, it's too big!